# How to tell if a variable is a specific type of dictionary? i.e. dict(int, str)

Tags: python, dictionary, types, isinstance

I have a dictionary -

```
d = dict(
    0='a',
    1='b',
    2='c'
)
```

How can I tell if `d` is a `dict` of type `(int, str)`?

In C# it'd be something like:

```
d.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<int, string>)
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have specific types.

Comment: You can mix and match different types of keys and values. `d = {0:'a', 'foo': 1}`

Comment: that's not a valid way to define a python dict

Comment: as indicated, dicts are hetrogenous, you'll have to check every item to be sure, e.g. `[(type(k),type(v)) for k,v in d.items()]`

Comment: That's not how you do duck typing to begin with. Python doesn't care if it's a specific type, it cares if it **acts** like a certain type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python dictionaries don't have types. You'd literally have to check every key and value pair. E.g.

```
all(isinstance(x, basestring) and isinstance(y, int) for x, y in d.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

Within a single Python dictionary, values may be of arbitrary types. Keys have the additional requirement that they must be hashable, but they may also cover multiple types.

To check keys or values in a dictionary are of a specific type, you can iterate them. For example:

```
values_all_str = all(isinstance(x, str) for x in d.values())
keys_all_int = all(isinstance(x, int) for x in d)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Python 3.7 you can do something like:

```
from typing import Dict

d: Dict[int, str] = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' }

print(__annotations__['d'])
```

and get back: `typing.Dict[int, str]`

there's a function [`typings.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) that might be useful in the future, but currently only knows about objects of type:

> function, method, module or class

[PEP-0526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) also says something is to be done about this